# Elements of other component instance getting affected

Tags: css, angularjs

I have list or some report data using that I am calling report component inside my home page,
such as

```
<div *ngFor="let report of reports">
    <kt-report [report]="report"></kt-report>
</div>
```

Inside report component i have some icons to display report as bar type of pie chart or table.
but when i trying to chage view type of one report the icon colour that is suppose to change only for particular report being clicked, styling of other icons also getting affected.

I have attached screenshot to highlight the issue better.
Here as you can see bar icon of other component instance become invisible when I hover on the bar icon of first instance.
I want that not to happen only the specific instance that I am changing should have effect.
I have attached image of dashboard page for better understanding.
[image]